# Methods for geotagging/displaying text documents

Tags: text, geotag

I'm wondering what methods folks are familiar with for geotagging/displaying text documents, or the text from a document.

For example, it's easy enough to geotag a photo and display it in ArcGIS or Google Earth, but what if I have an extended textual description of a place?

Is it possible to geotag that, export it as a shapefile, and display that text in a GIS?

One possibility seems to create a text field, but that seems limited in characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For ArcGIS v10 and greater you may add a text document as an attachment to a geodatabase feature class features.

> Attachments provide a flexible way to manage additional information
>   that is related to your features. Attachments allow you to add files
>   to individual features and can be images, PDFs, text documents, or any
>   other type of file. For example, if you have a feature representing a
>   building, you could use attachments to add multiple photographs of the
>   building taken from several angles, along with PDF files containing
>   the building's deed and tax information.

[Enabling Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000r000000)